# Persist actual calculated values in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, persist

I am using Spark with Scala. I would like to have Spark persist the dataframes with the calculated values, not with the calculation logic.
Essentially, given a dataframe `df`, I am looking for a Spark command, or a series of commands, that does the equivalent of the following:

```
val schema = df.schema
val data = df.collect()
val newDf = sparkSession.createDataFrame(sparkSession.sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(data), schema)

newDf.persist()
```

In my case, I am given df1 and df2, then I have to iteratively create more and more new dataframes based on previous ones. The code looks roughly as follows:

```
val metrics2 = doMetrics(df2)

val df3 = myCreationLogic(df1, df2, metrics2)
df3.persist()
val metrics3 = doMetrics(df3)

val df4 = myCreationLogic(df2, df3, metrics3)
df4.persist()
val metrics4 = doMetrics(df4)
...
```

I cannot generate df3, df4, etc. all at the same time. There are values in metrics3 that will determine the exact logic for the creation of df4. Essentially, df4 is a join of df2 and df3 with some calculations being done to populate the fields. If instead of calling `df.persist()` in the code above I execute the first piece of code for every new dataframe, my performance gets more than 10 times better.

My understanding is that Spark recalculates views created based on its tables every time I need to use them, even if the views are persisted (here I am saying "tables" when I mean dataframes that were created based on data outside of Spark and "views" to mean dataframes that are created by executing Spark SQL on other dataframes). This would be helpful if older dataframes could potentially change and I wanted the new ones to reflect these changes. As it stands, old dataframes do not change and I need to keep creating new ones based on these views. I can just stick with the option of calling `collect()` and then creating a new dataframe every time, but I think there must be a better way to do it directly in Spark. I am also hoping that using Spark commands would speed things up even more.

Comment: why can't you just compute df4 in one step without creating the intermediary dataframes? You can persist like this if you want, but if you're only creating df3 for the purposes of calculating df4, then you should just use one of the many transformation functions that takes a DF and returns another DF. That way, you can compute df4 in one command.

Comment: I am using df3 for other purposes as well. I need all the intermediate DFs I am generating. I just didn't want to clutter the question with this. I am generating a whole bunch of DFs, each is used to generate the next, but is also needed in its own right. Most of what `doMetrics` generates is used by other logic and for logging, not just to generate the subsequent DF. Essentially, I am running something similar to gradient descent. I simplified the example to focus on the actual issue I am having right now.

Comment: It shouldn't recompute the DF if you've persisted it, and use the same variable.

Comment: I have a `Storage` class where I store the DF because `doMetrics` here is actually a stand-in for quite a bit of complicated logic, executed by different classes, so I need a location where I can store the DF, along with some of the partial results. `Storage` has method `store(df: DataFrame)` which calls `df.persist()`. Then I retrieve the stored DF for various purposes using a `getStored()` method, including to generate the next DF. Do you think that not using the same variable name on which I call `persist()` might cause this slowdown?